# C++ Using std::string functions for MBCS and std::wstring functions for UTF-16

Tags: c++, windows, string, utf-16, mbcs

Has anyone dealt with using std::string functions for MBCS? For example in C I could do this:

```
p = _mbsrchr(path, '\\');
```

but in C++ I'm doing this:

```
found = path.find_last_of('\\');
```

If the trail byte is a slash then would find_last_of stop at the trail byte? Also same question for std::wstring.

If I need to replace all of one character with another, say all forward slashes with backslashes what would be the right way to do that? Would I have to check each character for a lead surrogate byte and then skip the trail? Right now I'm doing this for each wchar:

```
if( *i == L'/' )
*i = L'\\';
```

Thanks

Edit: As David correctly points out there is more to deal with when working with multibyte codepages. [Microsoft says use _mbclen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh2z6hz) for working with byte indices and MBCS. It does not appear I can use find_last_of reliably when working with the ANSI codepages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special about surrogate pairs. A single 16 bit character unit that is one half of a surrogate pair, cannot also be a non-surrogate character unit.

So,

```
if( *i == L'/' )
    *i = L'\\';
```

is perfectly correct.

Equally you can use `find_last_of` with `wstring`.

It's more complicated for multi-byte ANSI codepages. You do need to deal with lead and trail byte issues. My recommendation is to normalise to a more reasonable encoding if you really have to deal with multi-byte ANSI date.

Comment: Wait does the same apply to MBCS?

Comment: David yes, the ANSI codepages as well. because I'm pretty sure MBCS can give slash characters in the trail byte. Do you know what I should do in that situation. And thanks for your answer so far

Comment: Nothing to worry about in any ANSI codepage, `find_last_of` is fine there. Even with UTF-8 you can search for `'\\'` without worrying about multi-byte encoding issues. That's because all code points that require multiple bytes in UTF8 have 1 for their most significant bit.

Comment: No, that's right. I'm forgetting the multi-byte ANSI codepages.

Comment: So then don't use find_last_of with MBCS? Can you update your answer for that situation

Comment: Yeah, done that. I would try to avoid MBCS though. Do you really need to deal with it? Can't you stick to UTF-16.

Comment: Yeah I have to write something that can be compiled with or without UNICODE/_UNICODE. What I'll probably do is call the UNICODE versions of the API functions regardless and then I'll do whatever I need to do and convert to ANSI codepage if necessary. Thanks